# How to query the range of polygons with java geoTools lib?

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I have a lot of coordinate points. Now I draw a polygon on the map and query the points within this range, such as gas stations in the United States.

[image]

All my data is stored in ArrayList. How can I achieve this through java geotool lib

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Put your points in a datastore or feature collection and use a filter.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401531/how-increase-speed-of-counting-cql-tofiltercontainsthe-geom-point-lat-lon/401907#401907) (on the more relevant  https://gis.stackexchange.com) shows several possible ways of solving this problem with different speeds. They all come down to basically using a filter (constructed from your `Polygon`) to return the subcollection of features (your points) from a datastore.

So first we need a `DataStore` of point features (Gas Stations) ideally this would be a spatially enabled database (so the query is done in the database with indexes etc), but a shapefile or CSV would be OK if you only have a few hundred records or are only doing the query a few times.

Once you have a datastore, you can get a `SimpleFeatureCollection` and then you call the `subCollection` method with your filter.

The easy way to create a `Filter` is to use the `CQL.toFilter` method which takes a string like:

```
Filter filter = CQL.toFilter("intersects(the_geom,"POLYGON((1 2, 2 4...,1 2")");
```